# MYSQL: select only column with sum == 0

Tags: mysql

I have a similar table:

```
+----+--------+--------+------------+-----------+
| id | amount | rif_id |    date    | is_closed |
+----+--------+--------+------------+-----------+
|  1 | 20     | NULL   | 2017-11-12 | 1         |
|  2 | -5     | 1      | 2017-11-13 | NULL      |
|  3 | -10    | 1      | 2017-11-24 | NULL      |
|  4 | 7      | NULL   | 2017-11-25 | 0         |
|  5 | -5     | 1      | 2017-11-26 | NULL      |
|  6 | -5     | 4      | 2017-11-28 | NULL      |
|  7 | 11.20  | NULL   | 2017-11-30 | 0         |
+----+--------+--------+------------+-----------+
```

I need to get a list of more recent ID where SUM of amount is equal to zero, refering with rif_id.

In my example, I need to get this result:

```
+----+--------+--------+------------+-----------+
| id | amount | rif_id |    date    | is_closed |
+----+--------+--------+------------+-----------+
|  5 | -5     | 1      | 2017-11-26 | NULL      |
+----+--------+--------+------------+-----------+
```

**I need the ID 5 because that -5 amount, with sum of ID 1, 2 and 3, is exactly zero.**

FYI, The column "is_closed" is updated with 1 when is inserted last transaction inside the table. In effect, when is inserted the ID 5, my script calculate and update the ID 1 with "is_closed" 1. Don't know if can be important for the SQL SELECT create.

Comment: rif_id for id 1 is null. There's no connection to the records of rid_id =1.

Comment: @fancyPants yes, but for ID 1 the rif_id is 1.... :)

Comment: Not in your sample data.

Comment: @fancyPants I'm sorry, I did write hurry. You can "imagine" that rif_id of 1 is 1.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this:

1. get all records with the same `ref_id` and has `id <` the current record
2. Filter only the records with acumulated value equals 0. `sum(t2.amount) = 0`
3. Sort by the id and get the first one. `Order by id desc Limit 1`

```sql
Select
    t1.id,
    t1.amount,
    t1.rif_id,
    t1.date,
    t1.is_closed
From
    table t1
    left join table t2 on t2.ref_id = t1.ref_id and t2.id < t1.id
Group by
    t1.id,
    t1.amount,
    t1.rif_id,
    t1.date,
    t1.is_closed
Having
   sum(t2.amount) = 0
Order by
   id desc
Limit 1
```

Comment: Sorry, where come from "t2" ?

Comment: It is the same table. Joining the table with itself to calculate the acumulated value and check when it becomes 0.